# Best way to cache data in Android with ViewModel and RxJava2

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, rx-kotlin

In my application I'm using RxJava2 and new class from Architecture Components ViewModel. In my case, I need to push SQL clause to ViewModel, which will do some magic and return Observable that will give me the data I need. Everything works fine, but I am not sure if I am using RX in the best way.

My data flow:
ViewModel has PublishSubject on which I am pushing SQL's. ViewModel has also Observable which is created by mapping subject. Also, I used distinctUntilChanged on Subject, to prevent from executing the same query again. 
 To cache data I used replay(1).autoconnect(1) on Observable, but that approach had a flaw. Sometimes my Subject pushed Sql when Observable wasn't yet connect, and my data never arrived to me. Should I use BehaviourSubject? Or maybe I shouldn't use replay(1).autoconnect(1) in the first place? Or maybe my whole flow is wrong? Example:

```
val listSubject: Subject<RawSql> = PublishSubject.create()
val sqlListEmitter: Observable<List<T>> =
        listSubject
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .map { // SOME MAGIC HERE }
                .replay(1).autoConnect(1, { compositeDisposable.add(it) })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case `autoConnect()` just waits for the first subscription to `connect()` to your stream. Since your subject and your stream build an inherent entity, you might not want to wait for it at all and instead connect it directly.

```
val listSubject: Subject<RawSql> = PublishSubject.create()
val sqlListEmitter: Observable<List<T>> =
        listSubject
                .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .map { // SOME MAGIC HERE }
                .replay(1)
                .let {
                    it.connect(compositeDisposable::add)
                    it.publish()
                }
```

Also you might need to change `subscribeOn()` to `observeOn()`. The subject emits on the same thread as the data is pushed to it and does not consider the thread it's subscribed on.

Comment: That is correct, but if i have two listEmitters connected to one listSubject, and I am observing only to one of them, still both will execute query, so I need another solution. How about replay(1) with autoconnect(1) and BehaviourSubject? I would get Sql even if Subject will emit it after i connect to it, am I right?

Comment: This sounds feasible. Anyway use `observeOn()` instead as well.